# Why does `ns` and `rcs` generate different predictions in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression, spline, rms

My understanding is that `rcs()` (from the `rms` package) uses a truncated-power basis to represent natural (restricted) cubic splines. Alternatively, I could use `ns()` (from the `splines` package) that uses a B-spline basis.

However, I noticed that the training fits and testing predictions could be very different (especially when `x` is extrapolated). I'm trying to understand the differences between `rcs()` and `ns()` and whether I could use the functions interchangeably.

Fake non-linear data.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(splines)
library(rms)

set.seed(100)

xx <- rnorm(1000)
yy <- 10 + 5*xx - 0.5*xx^2 - 2*xx^3 + rnorm(1000, 0, 4)
df <- data.frame(x=xx, y=yy)
```

Fit one model with `ns` and another with `rcs` with the same knots.

```r
ns_mod <- lm(y ~ ns(x, knots=c(-2, 0, 2)), data=df)

ddist <- datadist(df)
options("datadist" = "ddist")

trunc_power_mod <- ols(y ~ rcs(x, knots=c(-2, 0, 2)), data=df)
```

Examine their fits (MSE).

```r
mean(ns_mod$residuals^2)
mean(trunc_power_mod$residuals^2)

df$pred_ns <- ns_mod$fitted.values
df$pred_trunc_power <- trunc_power_mod$fitted.values

df_melt <- df %>% 
  gather(key="model", value="predictions", -x, -y)

ggplot(df_melt, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.1) +
  geom_line(aes(x=x, y=predictions, group=model, linetype=model))
```

[image]

Generate a test data set and plot the predictions between the two models.

```r
newdata <- data.frame(x=seq(-10, 10, 0.1))

pred_ns_new <- predict(ns_mod, newdata=newdata)
pred_trunc_new <- predict(trunc_power_mod, newdata=newdata)

newdata$pred_ns_new <- pred_ns_new
newdata$pred_trunc_new <- pred_trunc_new

newdata_melted <- newdata %>% 
  gather(key="model", value="predictions", -x)

ggplot(newdata_melted, aes(x=x, y=predictions, group=model, linetype=model)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image: predictions]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a fairly simple explanation:  `knots` is not an argument to `rcs()`.  It wants the knots to be specified using parameter `parms`.  Another issue is that the `knots` parameter to `ns()` doesn't specify the "boundary knots", which default to `range(x)`.  So to get the same predictions, you need

```
trunc_power_mod <- ols(y ~ rcs(x, parms=c(min(x), -2, 0, 2, max(x))), data=df)
```